# How to change vertex group weights of a mesh based on active shapekey?

Tags: vertex-groups, vertex-weights

Not sure if the title is right, but here is my problem:
I have a Jacket mesh with a shapekey that makes it into a jacket tied around the waist, the jacket is controlled by the character's armature. I want to change the weights of the jacket's vertex groups when the waist-shapekey is applied so that the waist-tied jacket is not deformed with the character's chest, shoulder bones etc. as those bones should not influence the jacket anymore. How do I go about doing this?
Example:
[image: This is the default mesh with all the bones deforming it correctly]

[image: Here the shapekey is applied and the red bones should no longer be deforming the mesh]

The first image is the normal mesh with bones deforming it correctly.
In the second image the shapekey is applied and I want the red bones to no longer deform the mesh as seen.

Comment: could you please show some screenshots? it would help to understand

Comment: added screenshots

Comment: What you could do is deactivate the bone's Deform option, and keyframe, but does it answer completely your question?

Comment: I still want those bones to deform other meshes but just not this mesh in particular

Comment: yes that's what I thought, so maybe use other bones, that are only dedicated to this part? Maybe if you show the real situation it will help to find a solution (mask anything you don't want to show)